# Develop VSPackage (VSX) using VC++ ? Need reference materials and links

Tags: vsx

I have a requirement where I need to extend or customize the Visual Studio using Visual Studio SDK using C++ or VC++. I have fallen out of luck and have found all the book, blogs and msdn customizing Visual Studio using C#. Need help to share me links and books on customization of VS using C++.

Regards
John.

Help appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2005 SDK comes with few samples (FigPkg, BscPrj, MyCPrj) demonstrating extending VS using native C++. It's a good way to start.

Newer versions of SDK don't contain this samples. But VSx COM API has not changed too much. Learning internals of different non-C++ projects (MPF, MPF For Projects, VisualD) can also help you better understand how VS-extensions work.